# How to prevent re-rendering the component which is inside router, when the state of super component changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When I update the state of the parent component, the child component inside of it which is wrapped with a router is re-rendered as well which restarts the state of the child components to its initial value.
Even when I don't pass any props to the child and without any dependency.

How can I prevent this? 
You can find the demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-dawn-4g5wd?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). Just toggle the state of child component and then change the state of the parent then you will see what is happening.

Comment: I don't think you can. If the parent rerenders it will rerender all the child components. How about keeping your state centralized with something like Redux so you can keep the state of the child component also in there.

Comment: Centralizing states makes help by keeping old state alive but doesn't solve the problem _ still  re-rendering happens _

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a simple fix for your problem!

In `index.js`, change this line:

```
<Route exact path="/" component={props => <Sub {...props} />} />
```

With this:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => <Sub {...props} />} />
```

The difference between the `component` and `render` props with an anonymous function is that `component={() => <YourComponent />}` will always re-render when the parent does. With `render`, though, re-rendering only happens when necessary.

I would recommend reading this article if you want to know more on the subject: https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/.

I have forked your CodeSandbox example here to see the difference: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-fermat-m01ct